# Can I give my docker-compose apps a local URL?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My docker compose file is spinning up multiple apps at ports `8081`,`8082`,`8083`,etc...

This is fine, but it can get a bit dull to keep track of the port for each webapp.

- http://localhost:8081 # Application 1
- http://localhost:8082 # Application 2
- http://localhost:8083 # Application 3

Ideally I'd have the apps running on `localhost/application1/` `localhost/application2/` etc...

Something like:

- http://localhost/application1/
- http://localhost/application2/
- http://localhost/application3/

This will also make it easier for me to share the urls with colleagues in my local network, and also avoid hard-coding the port number.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: U should use a reverse proxy: check this article that will help u to configure it: https://danielstoyanoff.medium.com/create-friendly-urls-for-your-local-dockers-3b35f676c341

Comment: In that case, you need an internal router. I guess that you can spawn nginx service in your composer and expose the nginx service at port 80, then nginx will route to the correct application.
You cannot use the URL path logic in docker composer since they expect to use different ports
https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-Multiple-Containers.php

Comment: Hmm, but is there no way for each docker container to expose "their" port 80, and then have the proxy service figure out what port each of them are? I'll read the articles, maybe that will help.